# what is equivalent control for TableCursor of SWT Table in nebulla Grid?

Tags: eclipse, grid, cursor, swt, rcp

my question : I want to replace the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table entirely in my view with org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.Grid. Almost all properties of the SWT table are also found in nebulla Grid and hence I can achieve most functionalities of SWT table in nebulla Grid. Now the greatest problem is that I have used org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableCursor in my SWT table for editing the values in the cells of the table which is perfect. But I didn't found any such equivalent in nebulla Grid and hence failed to achieve cell-data editing functionality in nebulla Grid. Somebody help me to achieve this in nebulla Grid or suggest me for the alternative way to do this in nebulla Grid.